# 24 hour Clock Timeline (radial timeline)

Tags: html, css, asp.net, clock, timeline

Can anyone assist with the below?

I have an Asp.Net application which we use to measure time and productivity.

The system itself is very simple - recording the user's Windows user name, StateID and eventFrom time (using server Getdate() function in MSSQL)

The EventTo datetime is Null on each insert but should the user change to a new state - for example they select lunch break, the stored procedure then does an Update on the previous record with the Null EventTo field for the user and creating a new row with the new state leaving the EventTo field nulled again.

System has been up for over a year now and has been running stable - we even use it for our client billing hours!

I have been having some issues however displaying the results in a user friendly way and would appreciate a css html solution that looks similar to the below

Would like to bind the data on code behind or using a SQL datasource control

I have tried donut charts but these always start their range at 00:00 (midnight)

With our employees starting their shift at 09:00 I would like the donut "area" for their working time to show as an example

09:00 - 09:00 Login
09:00 - 09:15 Meeting
09:15 - 11:00 WebChat
11:00 - 11:15 Tea break
11:15 - 16:00 Email
16:00 - 16:30 Lunch break
16:30 - 18:00 WebChat
18:00 - 18:00 Logout

Currently I have these states colour coded and the history is displayed within a vertical timeline using - I would like to make this radial

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaSRw.png)

[Currently this is displayed using bootstrap]

```
    <div class="timeline">
        <h3>History</h3>
            <ul>
            <asp:Repeater ID="rpr_TimeLine" runat="server" DataSourceID="TimeLine">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li class="<%# Eval("CSSClass") %>"><span></span>
                        <div>
                        <div class="title"><i class="<%# Eval("FontAwesome") %>"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%# Eval("StateName") %></div>                            
                        <div class="info h4"><%# Eval("Duration") %></div>      
                        <div class="info">Source: <%# Eval("DataSource") %></div>
                        </div> <span class="number"><span><%# Eval("StateTo", "{0:hh:mm:ss tt}") %></span> <span><%# Eval("StateFrom", "{0:hh:mm:ss tt}") %></span></span>
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>            
            </ul>
        </div>
```

[Display using a vertical time line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaSRw.png)

Comment: If you share the essential parts of the code you have so far it will make it far easier for us to help. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: How can a asp.net based application get the windows user name? that is not possible. when I visit YOUR site, you can't get things like my computer, or my user name - it not exposed, not allowed, and not possible in. I suppose if the server and users are ALWAYS on the same network and IP address is used by server code to get station name? Perhaps you are suggesting that users have to login first, but that's not work station name, is it? or you suggesting that all users are on the same domain then?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry a bit more information, this is an intranet application using windows authentication.

Comment: [Display using a vertical timeline][1]
[Suggested UI][2]
[Looking for something similar][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaSRw.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieR0j.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfKB3.png